# Scrapy returning 301 for reddit.com

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape, reddit

I'm using reddit as the basis for learning scrappy. It was working fine for a while, but now it always returns a 301 redirect, even when simply calling the shell with "scrapy shell www.reddit.com". Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Pretty sure it would error without having a preceding http or https

Answer (score 0):

use the https/http scheme in the url

```
scrapy shell https://www.reddit.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something related to reddit itself as it seems blocking your IP or user agent, you need to try tweaking the following : 
 1- Raise the DOWNLOAD_DELAY in scrapy settings 
 2- Try to change your user agent 
 3- Use proxy with scrapy

For more info on the settings:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

For scrapy proxy : 
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html